# Condencing a large " } else if { " statement in Processing

Tags: arduino, processing

I'm trying to do a project in which different images will be shown dependent on someones distance from an ultrasonic range sensor. I'm using both Processing and Arduino and have 37 images total. Right now though I just have a mass "else if" statement controlling everything at what distance the images will be shown, but to be frank its quite ugly looking. Is there a way to clean it up?

This is what it looks like

```
 if( val == 42) {
      img = loadImage("a_frame1_0.jpg");
      image(img, 0, 0);
    } else if (val == 41) { 
      img = loadImage("a_frame1_1.jpg");
      image(img, 0, 0);
    } else if (val == 40) { 
      img = loadImage("a_frame1_2.jpg");
      image(img, 0, 0);
    } else if (val == 39) { 
      img = loadImage("a_frame1_3.jpg");
      image(img, 0, 0);
    } else if (val == 38) { 
      img = loadImage("a_frame1_4.jpg");
      image(img, 0, 0);
    } else if (val == 37) { 
      img = loadImage("a_frame1_5.jpg");
      image(img, 0, 0);
    } else if (val == 36) { 
      img = loadImage("a_frame1_6.jpg");
      image(img, 0, 0);
    } else if (val == 35) { 
      img = loadImage("a_frame1_7.jpg");
      image(img, 0, 0);
...
```

If I need to put more of my code in here, I can do that as well.

Comment: Put the file names in an array. Then you end up with `path = images[val]; img = loadImage(path); image(img, 0, 0);`

Comment: @ikegami's idea (+1) is what I originally thought of, but if you have a general trend that you know there won't be exceptions for, you can really just do: `img = loadImage("a_frame1_" + (42 - val) + ".jpg");`

Comment: If the file names are predictable, then the way to go is definitely to generate the file names like Jeremy showed.

Comment: The only time there would be an exception is for my first image which will read something like "at 44 inches away and farther, show this image" I'm not sure if that would be a problem with the idea @Jeremy is suggesting.

Comment: @ChristineAustin Nah, a quick conditional will get you past that. Using the array solution would require the same conditional, so generating it via subtraction is probably your best bet (that way you won't have to add an array to the program's memory)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a for loop?

```
int min = 0;
int max = 42;

for (int i = max; i >= min; i--){

  if(val != i){
    continue;
  }

  img = loadImage("a_frame1_" + (max - i) + ".jpg");
  image(img, 0, 0);
  break;    
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I suppose that this large statement is placed in your `draw()` function. Loading image every time you draw your scene is very time consuming and could be problem on platform like `arduino` so I suggest that you load all images in the `setup()` function, store them in array as suggested by @ikegami, and use some loop just to store these images (I suggest you to rename problematic first names so you could use simple string concatenation)

```
PImage[] images = new PImage[MAX]; //MAX = 37

setup() {
  for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
    images[i] = loadImage("a_frame1_" + i + ".jpg");      
  }
}
```

Then show image depending on position within your `draw()` function

```
image(images[42-val], 0, 0);
```

Just you need to be careful about indexes so they will be in range [0,36]

**EDIT**

As @cup mentioned in comments this wont work on standard Arduino toolset so you need to change expresion to somethink like this:

```
loadImage(String("a_frame1_") + i + ".jpg")
```

Comment: Very C#ish syntax.  This won't compile as it stands.  Suggest changing the expression to **String("a_frame1_") + i + ".jpg"**

Comment: Yes, maybe C#ish syntax but it compile and works with [Processing 2](http://www.processing.org/)

Comment: Fair enough - I wasn't aware of that tool - I just use the bog standard Arduino toolset.

Comment: But good point with Arduino standard toolset. I will add it to answer.

Answer (score -1):

Try using a use a Switch statement

http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/SwitchCase